# Text Covering Linear Stability Analysis of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a text that addresses linear stability analysis PDEs. To be clear, I'm not referring to von Neumann stability analysis of finite difference schemes. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a set of notes by Walter Strauss on stability of PDEs for a workshop talk I believe https://depts.washington.edu/bdecon/workshop2012/g_stability.pdf